# Facebook debugger not updating image correctly

Tags: html, facebook

I'm using the debugger and scraping and scraping and scraping but the image won't update. It's grabbing the correct image URL in `og:image` when I debug it, and I've checked the URL and it goes to the correct image, but for some reason every single time the link preview is showing the old image.

Everything I've read just tells me to go to the debugger and rescrape it and it should just be voila! new image. Am I missing something?

Comment: How are you serving the image? Is a CDN or some other caching involved?

Comment: It's served locally on the site through my resources > images folder.

It is a direct URL so https://example.com/resources/images/facebookshare.png for example. Not resources/images/facebookshare.png 

Not sure if that makes a difference